# BigQuery: Why am I seeing a blank row in my results when I run the following query? How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I've input the following query exactly as the instructor had shown in the certificate course that I'm taking, but when I run the query, the first row is appearing nearly blank, as shown here: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9vuI.png). This problem doesn't seem to be occurring for the instructor despite entering the exact same thing and I'm unsure how to fix it.

Please help!

SELECT
usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route,
COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
`bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10

I successfully ran the query, but I'm seeing a "blank" row in the results that I'm not sure how to get rid of. I was expecting to see 10 **complete** rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
  where tripduration is not null
GROUP BY
  start_station_name,
  end_station_name,
  usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

It appears that the table you are querying contains some "null" rows.  Typically, when we perform data analysis we want to "cleanse" the data.  I ran the following:

```sql
select (
SELECT
 count(*)
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
  where tripduration is null
  ) as isnull,

  (
SELECT
 count(*)
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
  where tripduration is not null
  ) as isnotnull
```

and found:

| isnull | isnotnull |
| --- | --- |
| 5828994 | 53108721 |

So ... approx 10% of the rows in the table seem to be invalid/poor/need filtered.

Comment: That did the trick! 

But how did you know to use the trip_duration column and not the other columns for the WHERE clause that you added?

Comment: I ran the initial query you ran and got the same results.  I used "trip_duration" merely because I was looking for *any* column that contained dubious value.  A quick test showed that *invalid* rows could be detected by trip_duration being null.  In a real world scenario, we would know more about the data and use that intelligence to determine which rows should be included and which excluded in our *real* calculation.   All this comes under the heading of "data cleansing".